# Python: How to convert a range of hours to Month, Day, Hour of a year

Tags: python

I have a bunch of data tables with 8760 rows representing each hour of the year in order from 12am January 1st to 11pm December 31. I want to create columns that show the hour of the day, day of the month, and month of the year like below:

```
+------+-------+-----+------+
| 8760 | Month | Day | Hour |
+------+-------+-----+------+
| 0    | 1     | 1   | 0    |
| 1    | 1     | 1   | 1    |
| 2    | 1     | 1   | 2    |
| ...  | ...   | ... | ...  |
| 814  | 2     | 3   | 22   |
| 815  | 2     | 3   | 23   |
| 816  | 2     | 4   | 0    |
| ...  | ...   | ... | ...  |
| 8758 | 12    | 31  | 22   |
| 8759 | 12    | 31  | 23   |
+------+-------+-----+------+
```

What python functions can I use to get the desired 'Month', 'Day', and 'Hour' columns?

Comment: How would you know if it's a leap year?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You need to work through tutorials on basic Python operations and capabilities; Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial site.  Most of all, look up the modulus operator, `%`.

Comment: I'd look into `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: @gnodab Leap years and daylight savings aren't considered

Comment: @Prune I could see how the modulus operator could be used for the Hour column, but how could you use it for the Month and Day when some months have 30 days and others have 31?

Comment: In general, you won't use modulus for that part.  You need to research how to convert a day-of-year number (sometimes included in a format called "Julian Date" to a month and day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interesting question. I post this answer, not to 'do your work for you', but in the hopes of encouraging further research and investigation as to *why* a bit of code works.  Then, this example can be taken further by the reader and edited to further suit your current and future needs.

From an educational perspective, this sample exposes a user to the `pandas` and `datetime` libraries.  Further research:

- `pandas.Series.dt` datetime accessor [Docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)
- How to use the `datetime` module to convert integers into a `datetime` object. [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- How to use the `timedelta` module for adding / subtracting dates and times [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

#### Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td

# Create the starting date as a `datetime` object.
start = dt(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
# List initialiser.
result = [start]

# Build a list of datetime objects for each hour of the year.
for i in range(1, 8760):
    start += td(seconds=3600)
    result.append(start)

# Initialise a DataFrame data structure.
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': result})
# Add each column by extracting the object of interest from the datetime.
df['8760'] = df.index+1
df['month'] = df['dates'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['dates'].dt.day
df['hour'] = df['dates'].dt.hour
# Remove the datetime object column.
df.drop(['dates'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

#### Output:

```
      8760  month  day  hour
0        1      1    1     0
1        2      1    1     1
2        3      1    1     2
3        4      1    1     3
4        5      1    1     4
...    ...    ...  ...   ...
8755  8756     12   31    19
8756  8757     12   31    20
8757  8758     12   31    21
8758  8759     12   31    22
8759  8760     12   31    23
```

Comment: Please do not do people's homework for them.  We do not want to turn Stack Overflow into a coding service.

Comment: @Prune - I understand. On the other hand, SO can be used as an education opportunity to expose users / programmers to new ways of handling issues and using libraries they (we) might not have considered before.  Please retract the downvote and reserve them for *incorrect* answers. Cheers.

Comment: For people to learn, you could improve your answer by explaining the code, so that people get more out of it than "copied it from the web".

Comment: "Can be used" does not imply "should be used".  Please refer to the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for an overview of the site's charter and methods.

Comment: @Bava Thank you for your answer. I had been looking at the datetime library expecting to find a function similar to the MONTH, DAY, and HOUR functions in excel. The datetime accessor was the missing piece I needed to get at those objects.